Hibernate 5 native query maps wrong values to columns
Hibernate 5.6.15.Final
I have 2 entities with 1-to-1 relationship, both have audit fields "createdBy", "modifiedBy", "createdDate", "modifiedDate".
class EntityA {
    ...
    EntityB myEntityB;
    String createdBy;
    Timestamp createdDate;
    String modifiedBy;
    Timestamp modifiedDate;
}
class EntityB {
    ...
    String createdBy;
    Timestamp createdDate;
    String modifiedBy;
    Timestamp modifiedDate;
}

And I wrote a native query
List<Object[]> rows = currentSession().createNativeQuery("SELECT o.*, d.* FROM mytable1 o JOIN mytable2 d ON ...")
                                      .addEntity("o", EntityA.class)
                                      .addJoin("d", "o.myEntityB")
                                      .getResultList();

However, EntityB instances that are returned as a response contain invalid values for audit fields - they just duplicate values of audit fields from EntityA instance.

Hibernate 5 relies on java.sql.ResultSet and column names when it maps from a query to an entity
However, java.sql.ResultSet specifies in docs:

When a getter method is called with a column name and several columns
have the same name, the value of the first matching column will be
returned

In Hibernate 6 this issue should be already fixed, since it relies on column indexes instead of names.
A workaround in Hibernate 5 might be to select the columns with identical names twice and set them manually. For non-native queries Hibernate does that itself (see Hibernate is selecting same columns twice. Why and what's the purpose?).
Example of workaround:
List<Object[]> rows = currentSession().createNativeQuery("""
   SELECT o.*, d.*, d.created_by as d_created_by, d.created_date as d_created_date, ...
   FROM mytable1 o JOIN mytable2 d ON ...
""")
                                      .addEntity("o", EntityA.class)
                                      .addJoin("d", "o.myEntityB")
                                      .addScalar("d_created_by")
                                      .addScalar("d_created_date")
                                      ...
                                      .getResultList();

for (Object[] row : rows) {
    EntityB b = ((EntityA) row[0]).getMyEntityB();
    b.setCreatedBy((String) row[1]);
    b.setCreatedDate((Timestamp) row[2]);   
    ...
}

